# a set between 2 continuous functions closed

Tags: real-analysis

Given f and g are two continuous functions from a metric space X to real numbers.
How can one show, that a set consisting of x from X with f(x)<=g(x) is closed in X.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Show that $h:=g-f$ is continuous. Then $$h^{-1}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr):=\{x\in X:0\le h(x)\}$$ is closed. (Why?) What does this tell us about the set $\{x\in X:f(x)\le g(x)\}$?

Comment: The set is closed, because h is continuous and [0,inf) ist closed because the complement is open in /R, and this is an equivalent set to the given one.correct?

Comment: Exactly correct!